# Change part of node color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, treeview

I have a `TreeView` and I need each node to support multi color text.

I don't really know how to put it into words so searching for an answer is a little difficult.

[image]

The picture above represents what I want to have but the only difference is I don't want rectangles I want the text inside to be orange. So part of the `Node.Text` would be of the default color and the rest would be orange. I don't know if this changes anything but each node would have two words the first one would be in default color and the second one would be orange. So I don't need to split one word into two colors.

Any idea where I should start looking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to owner-draw the text. Take a look at the [TreeView.DrawNode event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and specifically using the [OwnerDrawText value of the TreeViewDrawMode enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewdrawmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

From the link:

> Use this event to customize the appearance of nodes in a TreeView
>   control using owner drawing.
>
> This event is raised only when the DrawMode property is set to
>   TreeViewDrawMode values of OwnerDrawAll or OwnerDrawText. The
>   following table indicates how the TreeNode can be customized when the
>   DrawMode property is set to these values.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into this doc. Altough I have a hard time understanding how this event works. Msdn exemples aren't always the simplest ones in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [TreeView.DrawNode event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx). There is an example in the documentation.